# How to customize the paging.banner.some_items_found when using DisplayTag

Tags: java, struts, displaytag

I'm trying to customize the line `paging.banner.some_items_found` in the `displaytag.properties`, I'd like to change o remove some words  like 'item' from the message, in my code I have:

```
paging.banner.some_items_found={0} {1} found, displaying {2} to {3}.
```

and it gives me as a result e.g.

> 6000 items found, displaying 106 to 126

How can I display?:

> 6000 found, showing 106 to 206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{0} found, displaying {2} to {3}.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer, it's correct, my mystake was that I was modifying two different files; could you tell me why there are two files: displaytag.properties and displaytag_en.properties? Isn't it enough with displaytag.properties in English? I was modifying the displaytag.properties

Comment: There are two files, or even more, because that's what allows internationalizing the banner. If the user has a French locale, it will first search for keys in the displaytag_fr.properties, then in the default displaytag.properties. If the user has the English locale, it will first look for keys in the displaytag_en.properties, then fall back to the displaytag.properties if the key can't be found.

Comment: It couldn't be better, thanks @JB Nizet, it's good to know it.